# I use cas service,SingleRowJdbcPersonAttributeDao queryType not works

Tags: java, mysql, cas

I user cas service auth by UserName,Email,PhoneNumber,but respose to client info is setting this:

```
<bean id="attributeRepository" class="org.jasig.services.persondir.support.jdbc.SingleRowJdbcPersonAttributeDao">
            <constructor-arg index="0" ref="dataSource"/>
            <constructor-arg index="1" value="select * from sys_user where {0} {1} {2}"/> 
            <property name="queryAttributeMapping">
                <map>
                    <entry key="username" value="UserName"/>
                    <entry key="username" value="Email"/>
                    <entry key="username" value="PhoneNumber"/>
                </map>
            </property>
            <property name="queryType">
            <value>OR</value>
            </property>
            <property name="resultAttributeMapping">
                <map>
                    <entry key="Uid" value="ID"/>
                    <entry key="Num" value="Num"/>
                    <entry key="Guid" value="Guid"/>
                    <entry key="UserName" value="UserName"/>
                    <entry key="Email" value="Email"/>
                    <entry key="PhoneNumber" value="PhoneNumber"/>
                    <entry key="CreatedTime" value="CreatedTime"/>
                    <entry key="UpdatedTime" value="UpdatedTime"/>
                </map>
            </property>
        </bean>
```

show logs

```
2016-04-20 21:21:55,994 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.authentication.RegisteredServiceAuthenticationHandlerResolver] - Authentication handlers used for this transaction are [org.jasig.cas.authentication.handler.support.HttpBasedServiceCredentialsAuthenticationHandler@660adcb8, org.jasig.cas.adaptors.jdbc.QueryAndEncodeDatabaseAuthenticationHandler@2731a375]
2016-04-20 21:21:56,666 INFO [org.jasig.cas.authentication.PolicyBasedAuthenticationManager] - QueryAndEncodeDatabaseAuthenticationHandler successfully authenticated liuxm
2016-04-20 21:21:56,666 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.authentication.principal.PersonDirectoryPrincipalResolver] - Attempting to resolve a principal...
2016-04-20 21:21:56,667 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.authentication.principal.PersonDirectoryPrincipalResolver] - Creating SimplePrincipal for [liuxm]
2016-04-20 21:21:56,668 DEBUG [org.jasig.services.persondir.support.jdbc.SingleRowJdbcPersonAttributeDao] - Created seed map='{username=[liuxm]}' for uid='liuxm'
2016-04-20 21:21:56,668 DEBUG [org.jasig.services.persondir.support.jdbc.SingleRowJdbcPersonAttributeDao] - Adding attribute 'PhoneNumber' with value '[liuxm]' to query builder 'null'
2016-04-20 21:21:56,669 DEBUG [org.jasig.services.persondir.support.jdbc.SingleRowJdbcPersonAttributeDao] - Generated query builder 'sql=[PhoneNumber = ?] args=[liuxm]' from query Map {username=[liuxm]}.
2016-04-20 21:21:56,787 ERROR [org.jasig.cas.authentication.PolicyBasedAuthenticationManager] - org.jasig.cas.authentication.principal.PersonDirectoryPrincipalResolver@7aeb398a failed to resolve principal from liuxm
```

I want to respose infomation from username,but username maybe is UserName,Email,PhoneNumber.